# Delete all identical records from each set of identical records

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, polygon, point, delete

I have intersected a point and a polygon layer and I would like to remove all cases where two or more points intersect with the same polygon. I do not want to keep one row of each duplicate, but remove them all, so I cannot use Delete Identical. I have FID:s of the polygons in one column and would like to remove all cases of the same FID occurring two or more times. I am using ArcMap version 10.5.

Comment: Find Frequency of that fid. Copy it to points table and delete > 1.

Comment: Great it worked.